# Show Text value from function

Tags: firebase, flutter, google-cloud-firestore

i'm returning this function:

```
   countDocuments() async {
      QuerySnapshot _myDoc = await Firestore.instance.collection("biders2|question")
        .document('uB_UserName')
        .collection("1")
        .document(_name2) // q_id
        .collection('biders') // see above -> done
        .getDocuments();
      List<DocumentSnapshot> _myDocCount = _myDoc.documents;
      print(_myDocCount.length);  // Count of Documents in Collection

      return(_myDocCount.length.toString());   //<-- this return is not working
     }
```

---

In Scaffold:

```
Text(countDocuments().toString()),  //<- i want to show this value, here this should show 2 as result
```

[image: This image contains 2 documents as number]

Note: print console working fine and prints 2 as no. of documents.

The result coming shows Instance of 'Future String' but wants to show no. of documents from firestore.
Any help will be appreciated,thanks.

Comment: since `_myDocCount.length.toString()` returns a `Future<String>` you need to `await` it. just change the return of the `countDocuments` to `return await _myDocCount.length.toString()`

Comment: it returns, Instance of  'Future<dynamic>' instead of showing text